# What is the command of double parentheses in Latex?

Tags: macros

What is the command of [image]. in Latex? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` available in the `stmaryrd` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}


\begin{document}

$\llbracket a \rrbracket$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `fourier` package also provides macros called `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`.